# Can I set a '@NonNull' annotation to 'member' what is initialized in 'onCreate'?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-support-library

```
public class NonNullSet extends Fragment {
    @NonNull // android studio say 'Not-null field must be initialized.'
    String mInitializedMember;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Bundle arguments = getArguments();
        mInitializedMember = arguments.getString("NonNullParam", "this is not null");
    }
}
```

I want to set @NonNull annotation.
Is it possible?

Comment: Annotation are basically used by lint to highlight the code that does not respect the annotation's constraint.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. `@NonNull` indicates that a field will *never* be null. In your case it will be null from the time class is created (so the constructor) until `onCreate`. It's just like if you tried to mark this field `final` - sometimes the field is `null`, so this is not legal.

You could, however, create a method marked with `@NonNull`, and return your string from there. I believe (though I'm not sure) that if you assert that field is not `null`, Android Studio will handle it properly:

```
@NonNull
private String getMember() {
  if (mInitializedMember == null) {
    throw new IllegalStateException("Member is null");
  } else {
     return mInitializedMember;
  }
}
```